# Dynamic assigned Properties for CsvHelper.Configuration.ClassMap<T>

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dynamic, propertyinfo

I want to use `CsvHelper.Configuration.ClassMap` by dynamically assigned properties.

Usually you map a Property like this in a static manner: *You have to assign each property and its 'text to display'.*

```
using CsvHelper.Configuration;

        public sealed class CleanSQLRowDescriptorMap : ClassMap<CleanSQLRowDescriptor>
        {
            public CleanSQLRowDescriptorMap()
            {
                Map(f => f.OriginalIndex).Name("Original Index");
                Map(f => f.OriginalRow).Name("Original Row");
            }
       }
```

I want to do the following:

```
using CsvHelper.Configuration;

        public sealed class CleanSQLRowDescriptorMap : ClassMap<CleanSQLRowDescriptor>
        {
            public CleanSQLRowDescriptorMap()
            {
                // Filter by attribute (implementation returns PropertyInfo List)
                List<PropertyInfo> mappedProperties = CleanSQLRowDescriptor.Create().FilterPropertiesByAttribute();

                // Dynamically assign each property and its assigned 'attribute value'  
                // At the moment I mapped the PropertyInfo.Name, but I actually need to use the Property as the static example above.  
                // Also need to figure out how to get the Attribute value (DisplayName in this example).
                mappedProperties.ForEach(prop => Map(f => prop.Name).Name(prop.Name));
            }
       }
```

I currently have the following method used above:

```
            [DisplayName("Original Index")]
            public int OriginalIndex { get; set; }

            [DisplayName("Original Row")]
            public string OriginalRow { get; set; }

            public string DonotWantToAssignThis { get; set; }

            public List<PropertyInfo> FilterPropertiesByAttribute()
            {
                // This function already returns only the attributes that use
                // [DisplayName] and other attributes defined for other properties, 
                // ignoring other properties that do not have any of these attributes.

                return properties;
            }
```

How can I use the PropertyInfo List of items to dynamically assign the ClassMap?  I want to create a base class with these attributes as filters and all the classes implementing this base class would have the same capability, making it easier to 'maintain the mappings'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to figure it out, VS Code did not give me all the overloads for `Map()` function, so I missed overloads.

This one is used in all examples:

```
MemberMap<TClass, TMember> Map<TMember>(Expression<Func<TClass, TMember>> expression, bool useExistingMap = true);
```

I found this inside [JoshClose/CSVHelper](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/master/src/CsvHelper/Configuration/ClassMap.cs):

```
public MemberMap Map(Type classType, MemberInfo member, bool useExistingMap = true)
```

So instead of using 'Expression that requires the property name as TMember' which does not take the type I can now assign the `MemberInfo` directly.

The code below just shows a solution for a ***single attribute [DisplayName] by using its .DisplayName*** property value.
For additional Attributes like I have at the moment, I will need to handle the property value differently:

```
mappedProperties.ForEach(prop =>
{
   Map(typeof(CleanSQLRowDescriptor), prop).Name(prop.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayNameAttribute>().DisplayName);
});
```